# How to solve script's Invalid regular expression flags?

Tags: javascript

How can I solve this code error when running!

```js
var replaced = $("body").html().replace(/<td>YES</td>/g,'<span class="yes"></span>');
$("body").html(replaced);
```

I want to replace all

```
<td>YES</td>
```

with

```
<span class="yes"></span>
```

Comment: Your regex is `/<td>YES</` and the flags you passed are `td>/g` which are of course invalid. You need to escape the `/`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider:

```
$("td").filter(function() {
    return $(this).text() === 'YES';
}).replaceWith('<span class="yes"></span>');
```

This finds all the `td` elements and filters for the ones with `YES` as the only contents and the replaces them.

Answer (score 0):

try to use an escape character for the closing td in your expression

```
var replaced = $("body").html().replace(/<td>YES<\/td>/g,'<span class="yes"></span>');
$("body").html(replaced);
```